# $f(x)$ can't be factorize in $p(x)q(x)$ where where p and q are of degree $\le 3 $

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)=x^4+26x^3+52x^2+78x+ 1989$

$f(x)$ can't  be factorize in $p(x)q(x)$  where   where $p\ and\ q$ are of degree $\le 3 $

Comment: For your information: the highest power of the unknown occurring in a (univariate) polynomial is called its *degree*. We understood you - no problem. Just to help you in the future! Here you could phrse the last sentence to read: "... where $p$ and $q$ are of degree $\le 3$."

Comment: I apologize @JyrkiLahtonen, I should use the correct terminology.

Comment: Absolutely no need to apologize. Doing math in a foreign language is hard at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) for prime $p=13$.